# Seeing the ground from the shuttle before launch?

Tags: space-shuttle, astronauts, launchpad, ascent

With the side windows in space shuttle cockpit, as seen in this [photograph](https://www.nasa.gov/vision/earth/everydaylife/NASCAR.html),

[image]

could the commander and pilot see the ground at all before launch or during the first 10-15 seconds of a shuttle ascent?

From this angle it would seem a lot could be seen to the sides of the shuttle,[image]
screen grab from [video](https://youtu.be/yaVVns_sTGY?t=669).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a frame from a video I shot in the Shuttle Mission Simulator back in the 90s. I was sitting in the commander's seat. The shoebox with the red stripes is supposed to be the launch tower, you can see the ground at the bottom.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/Rh61hOE]

The simulator window field of view was supposed to be accurate. But although I didn't have a helmet on, I would say yes.